# Remotely deploy .war file into tomcat webapps

Tags: tomcat6, tomcat5.5

I have tomcat5.x and tomcat6 running on different machines. I usually use scp to deploy .war file to tomcat servers. Is there any other way to remotely deploy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scp is best way to deploy even you can use http://localhost:8080/manager/html browse deploy.war